# For package managers like pip, is it a better practice to install packages with the `--user` flag?

Tags: package-manager

I understand that for most package managers (pip, brew, TeX tlmgr, etc) packages are typically not audited, so there are some inherent security risks in using these package managers. Sometimes the package repositories aren't trustworthy either.

Would it be a better practice to install all packages with the `--user` flag? This is in the context of a user who does not normally have root privileges.

Comment: What are you protecting? The users data, or the system? Is it a single user system or a multi user system? What is your threat model?

Comment: Single user system (+ one root user). Hoping to protect _everything_. Threat model: none? I'm just asking this as a layman... @vidarlo

Comment: Installing packages system wide or for one user typically doesn’t change who the code runs as. It could theoretically be more secure in a multi user environment, for example a server where many people log in and run Python code. But in that case, untrusted users shouldn’t have the ability to install anything system wide.

Comment: Installing as the current user is the default behavior on Debian as of recently.

Comment: @David well, the install scripts would be run as root if you install them system wide, and there could definitely be malicious code in there.

Comment: @multithr3at3d that's kind of what I had in mind originally...

Comment: @downvoter: please could you explain how you'd like this question to be improved?

Answer (score 1):

As you said anybody can upload a package to PyPi, and the code is likely not audited, especially for little-known projects. Further, Python packages can execute arbitrary code as part of the setup process.

It is not too different from downloading some random repository off GitHub or some other site and running that as root. Naturally, it is a fairly bad practice to run untrusted code in general, especially as root.

In practice, it comes down to your threat model and exact setup. For example, if you install a malicious package under your user account and your user is a sudoer, you may as well have installed it as root since your user's privileges can be abused to get root anyway. As mentioned in comments, the user's data is at risk either way.

There are also many non-security related benefits to using user packages or virtual environments especially.

*Personally, I will typically only install Python packages as root if there is a distribution package for them. I use the user install for any packages I may want to use from the REPL for random purposes. Otherwise, anything for development or deployment goes in a virtual environment.*

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I am typically not a sudoer, so that's what motivated my question.

Comment: Even if your user is not a sudoer, most things on your computer worth attacking are under your account and not root (stored passwords to various sites, confidential documents, mails etc.) and running a bitcoin miner does not require root either.